# Problemas al ejecutar el comando "tsc -v"

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, npm

Estoy aprendiendo `angular` y para eso instalé `node.js` y en su defecto `npm` y por medio de `npm` estoy intentando instalar `type script` ejecutando el siguiente código en la consola:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

El registro termina exitoso, el problema es cuando quiero ver la versión o compilar cualquier archivo... me sale el siguiente error:

> "tsc" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

No sé a que se deba este error, si alguien sabe muchas gracias.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen donde se puede ver que al ejecutar el comando sale error como si no existiera o no pudiera hacer dicha acción

Answer (score 4):

El TypeScprit se actualiza con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install typescript -g
```

Y si la última versión 2.4.2 está instalada correctamente puedo verificarlo mirando la ruta que se muestra siguiendo el comando:

```
npm list typescript -g
```

El siguiente comando muestra una versión anterior (1.0.3.0):

```
tsc -v
```

Te recomiendo la siguiente [documentación](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) para iniciar con TypeScprit.

Comment: Hola... la versión isntalada es typescript@3.5.3 pero sigue ocurriendo el error... no puedo poner "tsc" en la consola... sale error y ya lo instalé como dice en la documentación

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I resolved by uninstalling node.js and microsoft visual studio code and reinstalling everything, then installing SypeScrpit using the TypeScript command line compiler installing it as a code.js package ... apparently the problem was that it had not run cmd as administrator.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
a mi me pasaba lo mismo lo resolvi desinstalando node.js y  microsoft visual studio code y volviendo inatalar todo, luego instalar SypeScrpit usando El compilador TypeScript de línea de comandos instalandolo como un paquete de code.js... al parecer el problema fue que no lo habia ejecute cmd como administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo tenia el mismo problema, y lo resolví abriendo el terminal directamente por Windows el "CMD" el powershell del terminal de VS no ayuda mucho con eso.

Lo volví a instalar dentro del VS con el terminal en CMD y corrio excelente.

Paso a Paso.

1. abrir terminal en VS que sea CMD (por defecto te ubica en la carpeta)
2. instalar nuevamente npm install typescript -g
3. alli puedes hacer el comando TSC sin problemas.

Espero te ayude.